# How to access content at the server end?

Tags: java, http, servlets, http-post

I have used the following code in my client:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(myString.getBytes("UTF8")));
HttpResponse response = this.execute(post);
```

I would now like to access the string on the server end. The handle method looks as follows:

```
public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException { ... }
```

The request only lets me access the content length and type but not the content itself. Any pointers?

I'm using java as a pl and the built in classes from javax.servlet.

Comment: You might want to tell us what kind of (web)server you are using, as well as the programming language/ framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the string as the sole HTTP request body instead of as a request parameter for some reason. So, to get it, you need to read the whole HTTP request body. This is in the servlet available by

```
InputStream input = request.getInputStream();
// Read it into a String the usual way (using UTF-8).
```

Note that this would return an empty stream when it's already been read beforehand, e.g. by calling `getParameter()` beforehand on the very same request which would implicitly parse the POST request body for that.

The more sane approach would be to send it as a normal URL encoded request parameter as follows (exactly like as those HTML forms by default do)

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myString", myString));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
```

so that you can in the servlet just do

```
String myString = request.getParameter("myString");
// ...
```